# is it possible to create cart functionality without woocommerce?

Tags: php, e-commerce

I was wondering about how I can create custom cart functionality without installing WooCommerce plugin. Is it possible?

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: @aidadev - HI . Have you succeeded

Comment: @MostafaNorzade yes, I did it in custom way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WooCommerce is not the only plugin that will do this for you. Perhaps you want to take a look at [this list](https://colorlib.com/wp/shopping-cart-plugins-wordpress/) of other options.

If you think of building a cart on your own, don't think of it too lightly. Especially the interface to a payment option will be difficult. You may take inspiration from [this code on github](https://github.com/cferdinandi/wp-shopping-cart/blob/master/wp-shopping-cart.php) that implements a simple cart with paypal payment.

Comment: Thanks, While you was answering, I found exactly the same code on github that you shared and it is really nice. I'm modifying it and works very nice. @cjbj